# How to import csv file from one linux server to another server(mssql server)

Tags: sql-server, linux, bulkinsert

I have a csv file in linux server with following data

```
1,Jared,Australia
2,Nikita,India
3,Tom,Germany
```

I have a below table in windows server where mssql present

```
create table test.test1(Id INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, Name NVARCHAR(50), Location NVARCHAR(50))
GO
```

When I tried importing the csv from linux using sqlcmd it is showing below error.

```
BULK INSERT test.test1 FROM '10.0.14.23/home/admin/test_bulkinsert.csv' WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',  ROWTERMINATOR='\n')
GO
```

Error:

```
Msg 4861, Level 16, State 1, Server STS-PC, Line 1
Cannot bulk load because the file "10.0.14.23/home/admin/test_bulkinsert.csv" could not be opened. Operating system error code 3(The system cannot find the path specified.)
```

How to import csv file from 10.x.x.x linux server to 10.y.y.y sql sever database table.

Please help me out.

Thanks

Comment: You're asking how to share files between Linux machines. This has little to do with SQL Server. If you can't access the remote file from the shell, you can't access it from SQL Server either. Have you set up NFS in the two machines?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I need to load the file from linux system to windows server system where database is presented

Comment: Loading from Linux to SQL Server is *not* the same as loading on SQL from Linux. The first is a "push" process, so you could use something like BCP, where as the other is a "pull" process, so uses something like `BULK INSERT`. Clearly, as @PanagiotisKanavos stated, the service account your SQL Server is running under doesn't have access to the Linux server. Does the Linux server have Samba running? Is `/home/admin/` shared in Samba? Does the share have at least supply `500` permissions? Does the service account have access to connect to said share under it's credentials?

Comment: The path you specify has to be reachable from the server the database is running on, which isn't true for a local UNIX path. You can either install & configure Samba and specify a UNC path, or upload the file to a location that the server knows & load it from there.

Comment: Why tag SQL Server 2008 **and** 2012  as well? Which one are  you *really* using?